# Ist »abholen« reflexiv?

Tags: reflexive

> Wer das Abschlussprotokol noch nicht erhalten hat, (der) soll es sich bei mir abholen.

Wäre der Satz ohne *sich* auch richtig?
Warum hat der Autor da *sich* gebraucht?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das "sich" im Beispiel ist nicht reflexiv (denn man kann sich nicht selbst abholen), sondern ein Dativ-Objekt (für wen wird etwas abgeholt).

Beide Versionen sind grammatisch richtig und bedeuten hier dasselbe. Das Wort »sich« in diesem Zusammenhang deutet nur an, dass das Protokoll für jeweils denjenigen bestimmt ist, der es abholt. Das geht aus dem Kontext, den die erste Satzhälfte liefert, aber ohnehin hervor.

Klarer wird die Bedeutung des »sich«, wenn man den kontextstiftenden Teil weglässt und dafür noch ein »für« oder ein »selbst« einfügt:

> Erwin soll es *für* sich abholen.
>   Erwin soll es sich *selbst* abholen.

Es ist nämlich auch möglich zu sagen:

> Erwin soll es für seinen Freund abholen.  (für + Akkusativ)
>   Erwin soll es für Ludwig abholen.  (für + Akkusativ)

oder auch:

> Erwin soll es seinem Freund abholen.  (Dativ)
>   Erwin soll es Ludwig abholen.  (Dativ)

Ohne diese Angaben bedeutet der Satz nur, dass die angesprochene Person etwas abholen soll, ohne anzugeben, für wen der abzuholende Gegenstand bestimmt ist:

> Erwin soll es abholen.

Der in der Frage zitierte Satz stellt aber einen Kontext bereit, aus dem ohnehin schon hervorgeht, dass der Abholer etwas abholen soll, das für ihn selbst bestimmt ist. Daher liefert hier das Wort »sich« keine neuen Informationen, könnte also auch weggelassen werden.

Comment: Damit wird aber die Frage ob „abholen“ reflexiv sei nicht ausdrücklich beantwortet.

Comment: @fdb Hab die Antwort ergänzt.

Comment: In Ordnung. "sich" ist hier dativus ethicus.